# How to group by Date Object in XML view with the sorter?

Tags: xml, odata, sapui5

I'm trying to group by date objects in my xml view. I have problems and hoping someone could give me a hand / explain what should / can I do?

As of now what happens is:

1. My controller receive from odata.
2. One of the field have data object that looks like DATE: "/Date(1430524800000)/"

I have tried

```
    sorter: {
      path: 'DATE',
      descending: false,
      group: true
    },
    groupHeaderFactory:'.getGroupHeader'
   }
```

But it doesn't work.

What I want:

1. Group by weekly or monthly view on the xml.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: OData truly does not support grouping but the UI5 does support it.

Answer (score 0):

In here you can have a look at a very simple example for a sorter: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/c4b2a32bb72f483faa173e890e48d812.html.

If your sorter works which means that the binding is fine then the sorting will should be working too.
There is the example from the link

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.InvoiceList"
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
<List
        id="invoiceList"
        class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
        width="auto"
        items="{
            path : 'invoice>/Invoices',
            sorter : {
                path : 'ShipperName',
                group : true
            }
        }">
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title text="{i18n>invoiceListTitle}"/>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <SearchField width="50%" search="onFilterInvoices"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <items>
        …
    </items>
</List>
</mvc:View>
```